# Invalid File Output AVAssetExport

Tags: ios, audio, swift

When i run my app and click the save button to save the two files mixed together my app crashes saying invalid file output.  I dont see why this error shows up because the two files being mixed are mp3 and output file is mp3.

Code:

```
 @IBAction func mixButton (sender:AnyObject!) {
        let oldAsset = self.player.currentItem.asset

        let type = AVMediaTypeAudio
        let audioFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file1", withExtension: "mp3")
        let asset1 = AVURLAsset(URL: audioFile, options: nil)
        let arr2 = asset1.tracksWithMediaType(type)
        let track2 = arr2.last as AVAssetTrack

        let duration : CMTime = track2.timeRange.duration

        let comp = AVMutableComposition()
        let comptrack = comp.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(type,
            preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

        comptrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), ofTrack:track2, atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), error:nil)
        comptrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), ofTrack:track2, atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600), error:nil)



        let type3 = AVMediaTypeAudio
        let s = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file2", withExtension:"mp3")
        let asset = AVURLAsset(URL:s, options:nil)
        let arr3 = asset.tracksWithMediaType(type3)
        let track3 = arr3.last as AVAssetTrack

        let comptrack3 = comp.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(type3, preferredTrackID:Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        comptrack3.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10,600)), ofTrack:track3, atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), error:nil)



        let params = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track:comptrack3)
        params.setVolume(1, atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600))
        params.setVolumeRampFromStartVolume(1, toEndVolume:0, timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(7,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(3,600)))
        let mix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        mix.inputParameters = [params]

        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset:comp)
        item.audioMix = mix
        mixedFile = comp //global variable for mixed file
```

}
}

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let savedFileTest = documentsPath + "/myfile.mp3"
    if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(savedFileTest)) {
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(savedFileTest, error: nil)
    }

    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(savedFileTest)

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixedFile, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter.outputURL = url
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3

    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch exporter.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            println("failed \(exporter.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            println("cancelled \(exporter.error)")
        default:
            println("complete")
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output file is *not* mp3. You can *say* mp3 but that doesn't make it one. I don't think Apple framework code *can* save as mp3. It can read it, but due to various licensing issues it can't write it.

Do it as an m4a, like this (I have starred the lines I changed from your original code):

```
let savedFileTest = documentsPath + "/myfile.m4a" // *
if (NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(savedFileTest)) {
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(savedFileTest, error: nil)
}
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(savedFileTest)
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(
    asset: mixedFile, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) // *
exporter.outputURL = url
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A // *
```

By the way, you're saving the wrong thing (the unmixed `comp` rather than the mixed `item`).

Comment: I already answered that. Look at what I said. Look at your own code.

Comment: But i want to get output file in mp3 formate,then what can i do??

Comment: Interesting about the mp3 licensing theory.  Apple must be playing the licensing because Music can convert music tracks to MP3, and Garage Band can export to MP3.  So, I wonder if licensing is really the issue here.

Comment: @SouthernYankee65 Oh yes, it's all part of the same issue. The very first thing it says in the Music app acknowledgments is "MPEG Layer-3 audio coding technology licensed from Fraunhofer IIS and THOMSON multimedia." So Apple is legitimately licensing the tech. But you are not Apple so Apple cannot magically endow _you_ with the ability to make MP3s in _your_ app.

Comment: Roger that @matt!  After commenting on this it seems like the powers to be that monitor my internet activity decided to load me up on mp3 licensing topics. LOL!  I appreciate it!

Answer (score -3):

You can export it to "AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie" and rename it to *.mp3.

Init export, here you must set "presentName" argument to "AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough". If not, you will can't export mp3 correct.

```
AVAssetExportSession *export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:sset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
```

Set the ouput type:

```
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;  
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
```

Export it and set the file name extension to "mp3".

Comment: I try this and I get AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11843 "Cannot write output file" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Change the output extension and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot write output file}